# Python Curses without clearing screen

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I would like to use Curses under Python without clearing the screen. The reason is that I would like my app to pop up a simple small menu over the existing screen and soon exit. It is acceptable, though not preferred, to leave the ugly pieces of the pop up menu on the screen upon exit. The idea is to use it for quick practical sysadmin apps and scripts where aesthetics is not important.

It seems that the Python init functions always clear the screen. I also remember seeing one non Python app do what I like a couple years ago, so I know it is possible, at least in a C Curses program.

Comment: I had the same question. I'm disappointed with the answer, but understand. Aesthetics are important to me, so I'll try writing a hack like this: take a screenshot of the window when my program starts, use an OCD to figure out the characters, then start Curses and reproduce the screenshot I took, then add my UI over it. Probably will require native code to get the screenshot since I don't think there's anything cross platform or pure python way of doing that. Might share the answer here if I'm able to make it work.

Comment: Did you manage to complete your app? How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not going to say "It can't be done", but I will say "It can't be done" with stock, out of the box Curses/NCurses.

The fundamental problem is that the curses library, when it is initialized, has no access to the current state of the terminal, notably what characters and glyphs are currently being displayed.

In the old days on a PC, the screen was memory mapped, so when a program ran it had access to the existing screen state in order to capture and perhaps restore it later.

For a generic smart terminal, that's not necessarily the case. On Linux, or the Mac, the terminal type is some kind of "xterm". On a windows console terminal, it's a ANSI style terminal (mind xterm is also a kind of ANSI terminal). Terminal type is the code used by the termcap/terminfo library that curses relies upon to know how to move the cursor, delete characters and lines, set color or reverse video, etc.

All of curses interaction with the screen is through the printing of ESCape sequences, rather than manipulating memory. It doesn't work with a framebuffer.

If you look at a list of [XTerm escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), you'll see there's nothing to report the contents of the screen back to the host program. However, there is an alternate frame buffer. An example of this is, perhaps, `vim`. When you edit a file with `vim`, `vim` takes over the entire screen. But when you exit, your original screen is restored. `vim` is switching to the alternate screen buffer, and does all of its operations there, and then restores the primary screen buffer on exit. But this is a simple switching exercise, `vim` does not "know", nor has access to, the contents of the original screen buffer.

If you use things like the Linux console (where you can switch screens using the FKeys), or a utility like GNU Screen, these are different. These rely on different concepts (device driver for the Linux console, and pseudo-terminals for GNU Screen), and the overall program maintains the state of each screen themselves. But this information isn't available to a generic program, that I know of. If it is, it's through some proprietary method and not Curses.

Answer (score 0):

Python's curses binding includes [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.filter), which does what is requested:

> **`curses.filter()`**
> The filter() routine, if used, must be called before initscr() is called. The effect is that, during those calls, LINES is set to 1; the capabilities clear, cup, cud, cud1, cuu1, cuu, vpa are disabled; and the home string is set to the value of cr. ***The effect is that the cursor is confined to the current line, and so are screen updates.*** This may be used for enabling character-at-a-time line editing without touching the rest of the screen.

Because the program only knows about one line, it will not clear the screen.  This is useful for single-line prompts (and if needed, the line can be cleared).

***Caveat***: this will still use the terminal initialization sequences, which (depending on the terminal description) may switch to/from the (xterm-style) [*alternate screen*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite).