# How to create autocomplete suggestion menu in interactive command line application?

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, command-line-interface

Suppose I have this code:

```
choices = [
    'north',
    'south',
    'east',
    'west',
]

direction = input('Direction: ')
```

When this is run from the bash shell using `python3 myprogram.py`, the user will be prompted to type in a direction. There are only four choices, so I would like to show the user an autocomplete suggestion menu similar to this example in vim, except that the menu should appear in the bash shell:

[image: completion]

The user should be able to cycle through the available choices by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the up and down arrow keys.

How can I use Python to build an autocomplete suggestion menu that appears in the bash shell?

I tried the `curses` module, but it is not suitable because it clears the screen (similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003011/python-curses-without-clearing-screen)). Do I have to manually manipulate ANSI escape characters?

Comment: `curses` really is your best bet.  I'm not sure where clearing the screen is a problem.  Is this a problem because you want to preserve previous programs output before you ran `python3 myprogram.py` or because you want `myprogram.py` to preserve all entered input *after* it is run.  If the the answer is the former, it may be possible to achieve this with gnu `readline`.  If the answer is the latter, then `myprogram.py` is "clearing" the screen where it should not.

Comment: @Jason I want the user to be able to see the bash shell even when the menu is displayed. Are you certain that `readline` can be used to create a menu as shown in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [Python Prompt Toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit), a library for building interactive command line applications in Python.

The library makes it easy to add interactive autocompletion menus:

[image: pgcli - Python Prompt Toolkit]

(Image source: [pcgli](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli))